# Concat strings to create a variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Declared following variables in VBA:

```
Dim name_red_m_2016 As String
Dim name_yellow_m_2016 As String
Dim name_green_m_2016 As String
```

Created new array as colors:

```
Dim colors as Variant
colors = Array("red","yellow","green")
```

I want run a loop through the array and inside loop i will be adding some autofilters based on color and store the filtered row count in the above declared variables. Somehow it is not working.

```
For Each color In ttm_colors
    .AutoFilter Field:=124, Criteria1:=color
    Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range
    name_& color &_m_2016 = myTable.Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
Next
```

Comment: try `myTable.Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count -1 = "name_" & Color & "_m_2016"` in place of `name_& color &_m_2016 = myTable.Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1`

Comment: Also anything that you write that doesnt change needs to be in quotations "" these in other words

Answer (score 0):

```
name_& color &_m_2016 = myTable.Resize(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1
```

This line is giving you errors, because it's not possible to do that. You can't concatenate inside a variable name.

I'd suggest a [Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f26wd2e5(v=vs.100).aspx). For example:

```
Sub colorCollectionTest()
    Dim colors As New Collection
    colors.Add "red", "red_m_2016"
    MsgBox "The entered color was: " & colors("red_m_2016")
End Sub
```